# iOS Background Fetch task issues: too infrequent & doesn't work when locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

On devices with iOS 7 and above, we need our app to use the Background Fetch iOS API. We need this since our server cannot implement push notifications, yet. To achieve this I have done following things:

1. Set the background fetch minimum time interval to 1 Min.

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:TIMEINTRVAL_DIFFERANCE_IN_BACKGROUND_FETCH];
   ```
2. Implemented the delegate method with NSURLSession Code to download the image.

   ```
     -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
   performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
   (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

   NSLog(@"Background fetch started...");

   UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

   [notification setAlertBody:@"backgroud fetch"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

   // 1
   NSString *imageUrl =
   @"http://www.spotonsoft.com/images/logo.png";

   // 2
   NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
   [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

   // 3
   NSURLSession *session =
   [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig
                                 delegate:(id)self
                            delegateQueue:nil];

   NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask =
   [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];

   [getImageTask resume];

   NSLog(@"Background fetch completed...");
   }


   -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
    downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
   didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
   {

       self.completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
   }
   ```
3. Set the background fetch mode in "info.plist".

Observations :-

1. The background fetch is invoked, I can see it in the logs. However, the average duration between 2 calls is far too high. E.g. many times 10-15 minutes.
2. The call only comes when phone is not locked.

Is there anything we might be doing wrong? Do share your experiences with the Background Fetch Task API, if any.

Answer (score 2):

> The system wakes up the app based on a user’s behavior, and aims to trigger background fetches in advance of the user launching the app. For example, if the user always uses an app at 1 p.m., the system learns and adapts, performing fetches ahead of usage periods.

(http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html)

It is perfectly expected that you see 10-15 minute intervals between background fetches.

You can trigger a background fetch to happen from Xcode's menu bar (while debugging) by selecting `Debug` -> `Simulate Background Fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to execute some code in app background state:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
task = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:task];
        task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task.

        if (connectedToNetwork) {
            // do work son...
        }

        [app endBackgroundTask:task];
        task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
```